# for loop with 2 variables

Tags: loops, for-loop

i am using for loop with tow iterator variables but when i compile my code i am getting tow errors:
expected an expression and identifier "i" is undefined.
Here is the code section i am using:

```
for (int i = 16; i <= 28 && j <= 0x8000; i = i + 4, j = j << 1)
  {
    GPIOB->BRR = 0xF000;        //Reset pins 12 - 15
    GPIOB->CRH &= 0x0000FFFF;   //Pins 12 - 15 set to zero
    GPIOB->CRH |= 0x44440000;   //Pins 12 - 15 input floating
    BFLD (GPIOB->CRH, 0xF << i, 0x1 << i);
    GPIOB->BSRR = j;
    delay (100);
    for (k = 0x0001; k <= 0x0008; k = k << 1)
      {
        if (GPIOA->IDR & k)
          {
            code = (m | (k << 4));
            count++;
          }
      }
    m = m << 1;
    delay (100);
  }
```

I tried to define "i" before the loop but then i got one error that says: `Declaration may not appear after executable statment in block.`

So can someone please help me and tell me where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems a problem of non C89 compliant code. What compiler are you using and what are the compiler options you're set? In this case you should just remove the declaration of i in the loop and declare the variable before the loop, the same way you did for j.

Comment: The problem was with the compiler. I am using ARM compiler V6, but now i use V 5 in µKEIL V5